# Is `HEAD` implemented as a file?

Tags: git

`HEAD` is a symref of the current branch.

I thought it is implemented as a file `ref/heads/HEAD` (just like `master` is implemented as `ref/heads/master`), but there is no such a file.

Is `HEAD` implemented as a file?

Comment: It is *today*. Whether it will be the actual file `.git/HEAD` in, say, Git version 3.14 in 2023, well, who knows. However, `master` is *not* necessarily stored `.git/refs/heads/master`, even today. It may instead be a line within `.git/packed-refs`. Switching all refs to use a database, instead of plain files, would solve the case-sensitivity problem on Windows and MacOS, so I expect this will happen someday.

Comment: Thanks. What files are supposed to be under `refs/heads/`? Why isn't `HEAD` under `refs/heads/`?

Comment: The `refs/heads/` name-space is for branch names. `HEAD` is not a branch name. Most of Git's refnames live underneath some name-space signifier, e.g., `refs/remotes/` for remote-tracking names, `refs/tags/` for tag names, `refs/notes/` for notes, and so on. The various `*_HEAD`s do not, so they reside directly in `.git` today.

Answer (score 3):

HEAD file is at the root (search for .git/HEAD) and its content is a "pointer -> to a reference -> of the commit", at the tip of the current branch.

On branch master:

```sh
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

On branch issue_99:

```sh
$ cat .git/HEAD 
ref: refs/heads/issue_99
```

As you can see, HEAD contains a pointer to another reference.
You can get this value also with:

```sh
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/issue_99
```

If you look inside the destination reference, you get the SHA-1 value:

```sh
$ cat .git/refs/heads/issue_99 
92fff2a187ff1a35fa8a721c31465fad289998bb
```

When you commit an object, it belongs to the branch you're on (issue_99), and that branch is fingerprinted with the SHA-1 you see here.

In simple words, HEAD means "current branch", defining a pointer to a reference. 
When you checkout, you just update that pointer.

See: [git reference](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References)

For better understanding, look inside .git/refs: it contains references to commit object hashes, in a human-readable format.
So, inside this dir, you find branches, remotes and tags.
In my case:

```sh
$ ls -F .git/refs/
heads/  remotes/  tags/
```

Note that heads contains files named as my local branches, in repository. 
In our example:

```sh
$ ls .git/refs/heads/
issue_99  master
```

They contain the commit hash you usually see:

```sh
git log -1 issue_99 
commit 92fff2a187ff1a35fa8a721c31465fad289998bb 
Author: deeper-x <albertodeprezzo@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 7 10:46:13 2019 +0100

fancy description of fooBar commit
```

Coming back to our .git/HEAD file, you see why is considered a "special" reference: it symbolically references to the tip of the current branch (to a "ref", inside the refs/ container).

Now you understand why, for example, when you want to remove a file from stage (unstage), mantaining modifications, you use:

```sh
git reset HEAD myFooBar.c
```

It's easy to understand what's happening: HEAD is the last commit of the current branch, and you're just resetting it, w/o touching the file.

Comment: Thanks. What files are supposed to be under `refs/heads/`? Why isn't `HEAD` under `refs/heads/`?

Comment: I extended my answer, IMO all you have to know is there. 
TL;DR: HEAD is a _special_ file, with different behavior and purpose from those in refs/